# Estimating cluster assignment using Stan

Tags: mcmc, stan, rstan

I am trying to fit a finite Gaussian mixture model with unknown mean and covariances using Stan. I am aware that as HMC can't be applied to sample from discrete distributions, the marginalization technique is usually used to infer mixture parameters using Stan. However, for my application, I need the data cluster assignments. What is the best way to infer them in Stan? Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter 13 of the [Stan User Manual](http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/index.html) discusses this in some detail. In short, you can calculate (in the generated quantities block) the posterior probability that an observation falls in each of a finite number of categories and then use that vector of probabilities to draw a category realization from the categorical distribution.

Comment: You will have a label-switching problem if you run multiple chains (or potentially even if you run one chain).  The problematic posteriors chapter discusses this as does the chapter Ben pointed to in the manual.  The latent discrete parameters chapter shows how to compute assignments in the posterior.  It's much more efficient than sampling.  Also, Michael Betancourt wrote a great case study on identifying mixture models (http://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/identifying_mixture_models.html).

Comment: The Stan manual is now in HTML; this chapter can be found here: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_18/stan-users-guide/mixture-modeling-chapter.html